# How to show the jQuery bootstrap-datetimepicker on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, onmouseover, bootstrap-datetimepicker

It is cool http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ I am using...

I do like

```
$('#ExpectedEndingTimeDataPicker').mouseover(function () {
     $("#ExpectedEndingTimeDataPicker").datepicker();
});
```

But no joy... it is showing when click the `input` tag only...

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control dataPickerField valid" 
       data-val="true" 
       data-val-required="The Expected Ending Time field is required." 
       id="ExpectedEndingTimeDataPicker" 
       name="Requsition.ExpectedEndingTimeAsString" 
       readonly="True" type="text" value="17.01.2014">
```

Comment: first issue, `datepicker` should be `datetimepicker`

Comment: I don;t think what you're trying to achieve is possible, the datetimepicker plugin is triggered on click, which means the jQuery element listen for a click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation ([github link](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)), use

```
$('#ExpectedEndingTimeDataPicker').data("DateTimePicker").show();
```

inside your mouseover handler.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#ExpectedEndingTimeDataPicker').mouseover(function () {
     $(this).data('daterangepicker').show();
});
```